# Simson's Line of any point on incircle wrt DEF and MNP are perpendicular

Tags: geometry, contest-math

From *Lemmas in Olympiad Geometry*, Titu Andreescu, Epsilon 8.6:

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $D,E,F$ be the incircle tangency points. Let the incircle intersect $AI, BI, CI$ at $M,N,P$ respectively.Prove that the Simson's Line of any point on incircle with respect to $DEF$ and $MNP$ are perpendicular.
>
> [image]

My Progress:

We know that $M$ is midpoint of arc $EF$ and similarly. If $G$ is any point on the circle with respect to which simson lines are drawn, then $KG||AI, GJ||CI, GH||BI$. I'm thinking there could be a possible homothety because of parallel lines.

I also tried a Steiner line claim, by invoking orthocentres of triangle $DEF, MNP$. However I haven't proceeded much.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prove the following lemma: Let $ABC$ be inscribed in a circle $\omega$. Let $P$ be a point on $\omega$ and let $Q$ be a point on $\omega$ such that $PQ \perp BC$. Then $AQ$ is parallel to Simson line of $P$ with respect to $ABC$.

Next, draw chords $GX$ and $GY$ perpendicular to $EF$ and $MN$, respectively. By lemma, you have to prove that $DX \perp PY$. This can be shown by angle chasing.